# Split data in Pandas rows to new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I could code line by line to achieve the result, but very much appreciate if someone can demonstrate coding this using loops.

Original File:

```
   Col1   
0  A1-Text1;A2-Text2
1  A1-Text1;A2-Text2
2  A2-Text2;A3-Text3;A4-Text4;A6-Text7  
3  A1-Text1;A2-Text2;A4-Text4
```

Desired Outcome:

```
   Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4  
0  A1     A2     None   None  
1  A1     A2     None   None
2  A2     A3     A4     A6
3  A1     A2     A4     None
```

Updating my query, how do I work with this instead?

```
   Col1   
0  A11.2-Text1;H22.0-Text2
1  A49.8-Text1;K52.8-Text2
2  Q28.3-Text2;D35.5-Text3;A64.5-Text4;A76.7-Text7  
3  A15.8-Text1;A27.5-Text2;A47.8-Text4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with a [`regex`](https://regex101.com/r/LKemwn/1) pattern:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(df['Col1'].str.findall(r'([A-Z0-9\.]+)-').tolist())
```

Alternatively you can try [`.str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) + [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
out = df['Col1'].str.extractall(r'([A-Z0-9\.]+)-')[0].unstack()
```

---

```
print(out)

       0      1      2      3
0  A11.2  H22.0   None   None
1  A49.8  K52.8   None   None
2  Q28.3  D35.5  A64.5  A76.7
3  A15.8  A27.5  A47.8   None
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response.
After googling your solution, I figured you are using regex. If i may ask further if my data include other alphabets other than A and there's float, how do i change the code?

   Col1   
0  A11.2-Text1;H22.0-Text2
1  A49.8-Text1;K52.8-Text2
2  Q28.3-Text2;D35.5-Text3;A64.5-Text4;A76.7-Text7  
3  A15.8-Text1;A27.5-Text2;A47.8-Text4

Comment: @Juxcy In that case i guess you can try `pd.DataFrame(df['Col1'].str.findall(r'(?i)([A-Z0-9\.]+)-').tolist())`